# sending notifications when accessing api page

Tags: django, rest, tastypie

When a user add a comment to an image,
some users including the author of the image gets notified via Push notification.

I had it working in a regular view.
Now I'm adopting tastypie framework, and converting this view.

```
class CommentResource(ModelResource):

..
   def obj_create(....):
        #send notifications
        #actually create the comment object
```

It just feels weird having `sending notifications` in API, so I'm asking 
if this is a fine practice.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that altough this works it may be suboptimal. Probably better would be to decouple the API and notifications using signals (here are [Django docs on signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/))

The main benefit would be decoupling notification code from API code. The signal listener isn't concerned with who or how or where created the comment, it just acts on the fact that the comment was created. Same applies to the API (signal sender). This allows you to change notification code without changing the API and vice versa. Of course that way the code is simpler and cleaner too - for example if you decided to do few more things with the comment, you'd just add more listeners instead of bloating your API code with more features which are rather irrelevant to the API itself and making it harder to maintain.

You could take all this one step further and develop an asynchronous version (Django signals are synchronous, which means when you send a signal the processing is blocked until signal listeners are done). This would be also very nice, because after sending the signal your API request processing code could finish without waiting for the notification to be sent. This would make the API respond faster from the consumer perspective. This could be done in a number of ways - using threading, Celery or Greenlet/Gevent, google is your friend here if you're interested.

Whether asynchronous is actually suitable depends on your exact requirements, i.e. you may actually be interested in sending signals synchronously becasue notifications might be very important for you, even if they make API responses slower.

Hope this will get you going :) Good luck!